# Cross OS GPU based malware

Tags: malware, hardware, operating-systems

I've been doing some research into GPU based malwares, and would like to know if there is a way to run them on a dual boot scenario with the code being executed only on one Operational System and be "stored" to also execute on the second one. Both OS's would be the same (two Linuxes, for example).

From what I understood, it wouldn't work on the popular [Jellyfish PoC](https://github.com/LucaBongiorni/jellyfish), since it defines an environment variable, which is not shared with the two systems.

Because it's needed to reboot to enter on the second system, I think there's no way to do it, however, I'd like to hear some thoughts about it.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple classes of malware that can run outside of the OS and thus work on a dual-boot system regardless of operating system. One such class is commonly referred to as a "Bootkit" and targets the UEFI or BIOS of a machine instead of the OS. These have been around for at least 10 years; real-world examples include [Mebromi](https://www.webroot.com/blog/2011/09/13/mebromi-the-first-bios-rootkit-in-the-wild/) and [badBIOS](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/meet-badbios-the-mysterious-mac-and-pc-malware-that-jumps-airgaps/).

Comment: BadBIOS is a stupid myth based on hypothetical malware design.